# Elgg 1.8.19 isn't sending validation emails with Postfix

Tags: php, apache, email, postfix-mta, elgg

I'm developing a social networking site using Elgg 1.8.19 on a Digital Ocean VPS that runs Ubuntu 13.10 and Postfix 2.10.2.

Elgg isn't sending validation emails to users, whether they have just registered or whether the validation emails are resent by the administrator. **Has anyone has this problem before and know of a solution?**

I've manually confirmed Postfix is working by telnet'ing  to port 25 and sending from there.

```
telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 localhost ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo localhost
250-localhost
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from: user@localhost
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: myaccount@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
testing email for stackoverflow
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 795AC120025
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I've also successfully run a PHP script to test the mail() function with the following:

```
<?php    
$to = "myaccount@gmail.com";
$header = "From: {$to}";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
?>
```

For reference, here's my Postfix main.cf:

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = jconnect-tb.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

I've been hitting Google and the Elgg Community discussion boards all day to no avail, as most posts refer to http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/No_emails_%28including_validation_emails%29_are_being_sent.  As far as that goes, it refers to php.ini configuration options that are already set.  **Any ideas where to look/solutions?**

Comment: Probably the only remaining question is: How is your Elgg configured to send mails?

Comment: look into postfix log file, what postfix does with those Elgg emails